# How to print all values with same key in one row?

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJS. I wanted to ask how to print all the values with similar key in a row, then another set of values with similar key in another row. For eg. I have to print employees name with similar age in one row etc..Can anybody give me a solution?

Comment: provide some JSON or code

Comment: {
{"employee_id":5,
"firstName":"Priti",
"lastName":"Lata",
"Age":24,
,"Role":"HR"},
{
"employee_id":6,
"firstName":"Sumita"
,"lastName":"Nath",
"Age":24,
"Role":"HLA Head",
"Department":"Crm"},
{
"employee_id":7,
"firstName":"Tarini",
"lastName":"Khanna",
"Age":22,
"Role":"Content Writer"
}}

Comment: an edit to question would have been better

Comment: I want it to be like .. employee with age 24 in same row

Comment: Use basic, vanilla JavaScript to transform your JSON into an array of objects containing an age, and an array of employees  with that age. Then use ng-repeat to display all the objects, and a nested ng-repeat to display all the employees of that age.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have data as array for ng-repeat.
Now, pre process that data in controller or service to group them based on the criteria ( same age in your case ) and then simply ng-repeat.

Comment: can u plz give some sort of pseudo code.. It will be very helpful !!

Comment: @SmritiRaj trying to do that by yourself would be even more useful. We're not here to do your homework for free.